# Writing a Regex for Kuwait Mobile number in international format

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match following:

- total string length 12
- first four characters must be +965
- fifth character either 5, 6 or 9
- followed by 7 digits [0-9]
- nothing else allowed

Any help regarding this shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: `/^\+965[569]\d{7}$/`

Comment: i have tried it but not working as expected. upon entering a valid number, it gives error.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: Tim, i m using it in simfatic forms

Comment: Are you trying to find this number within a larger string?

Comment: no, just using it for validation purpose

Comment: Then the regex given by @PranavCBalan should be working.

Comment: i amended it to be \+965[569]\d{7}    working fine on validations except the total string length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on help extended by Pranav and Tim, the regex for kuwait mobile is +965[569]\d{7}$

working fine with simfatic forms. Thanx for the help.